# doc2vec: any way to fetch closest matching terms for a given vector?

Tags: word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

The use-case I have is to have a collection of "upvoted" documents and "downvoted" documents and using those to re-order a set of results in a search.

I am using gensim [doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) and am able to run the `most_similar` queries for word(s) and fetch matching words. But how would I be able to fetch the matching keywords given a vector fetched by a vector sum of the above doc vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh silly me, I found the answer staring right in my face, posting here in case anyone else has the issue:

```
similar_by_vector(vector, topn=10, restrict_vocab=None)
```

This is however found not in the Doc2Vec class, but in the [KeyedVector](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html) class.

Comment: Note that the `doc2vec_model.docvecs.most_similar()` also takes raw vectors, but you should be explicit that you are providing a list-of-positive-examples to avoid the vector-array from being misinterpreted as a positive-examples-array. Specifically, call like: `doc2vec_model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=[new_vector])`.

Comment: Note that the `doc2vec_model.docvecs.most_similar()` also takes raw vectors, but you should be explicit that you are providing a list-of-positive-examples to avoid the vector-array from being misinterpreted as a positive-examples-array. Specifically, call like: `doc2vec_model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=[new_vector])`.